# Prevent leading and trailing spaces with RegExp

Tags: regex

We are looking for a RegExp which satisfies the following conditions:

1. The first 3 characters should be alphanumeric without spaces.
2. Next characters can be alphanumeric including spaces.
3. The pattern should not end with a space.
4. The length should be 3 to 20 characters.

We have something like this currently :

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{3}[\\sA-Za-z0-9]{0,16}[A-Za-z0-9]$
```

But the above Reg Exp accepts a minimum length of 4 characters and not 3. I am mainly facing problem in limiting the length from 3 to 20 along with the requirement that first 3 characters must be alphanumeric.

Comment: It would be great if you can share some samples.

Comment: `\\s` is usually equal to the literal character \ (you've escaped it) or the literal character `s`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I guess this is not the regular expression, but the string literal of the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
(?i)^[a-z0-9]{3}(?:[a-z0-9 ]{0,16}[a-z0-9])?$
```

You can test it out in [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/56).

- The `(?i)` makes it case-insensitive
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `[a-z0-9]{3}` matches the first three chars
- Optionally (thanks to the `?`), we match...
- `[a-z0-9 ]{0,16}` 0 to 16 alphanums or spaces, then an alphanum `[a-z0-9]`
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

What about?

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{3}([\\sA-Za-z0-9]{0,16}[A-Za-z0-9])?$
```

Just making everything beyond the 3 leading characters optional should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex,

```
^(?=.{3,20}$)(?:[A-Za-z0-9]){3}(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9 ]+)?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oP9gB7/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{3}[\sA-za-z0-9]{0,17}(?<!\s)$
```

`(?<!\s)$`: negative lookbehind - so that the `$` character is not preceded by a `\s`, i.e. there's no `space` at the end (allows multiple *spaces* in between characters)

--> [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kW5rH8/1)